# Graphics not showing up on Word, but on a PDF in SAS

Tags: graphics, sas, enterprise-guide

Everything in my SAS coding works. I have

```
  ods rtf "c:\...\name.rtf";
  ...
  ods rtf;
```

In my word doc, I just get an empty white square, with a message saying "...object created using SASGraph9. The program is either not installed or not responding..."

But when I create a pdf, I get my graph. I even tried to export it Word, I get the same message. Is there anyone who can tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: I don't see any graphics in that example code.  Please provide a [MCVE] so that we can see what you're actually doing.

Comment: What graphing procedure are you using? Use SGPLOT and make sure its set to a compatible type, not all types can work with all destinations.